# In case of torque on sliding block on horizontal surface, why $y$ component of $\vec{r}$ is taken negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, torque

[image]

I've attached the picture above. In case of the torque on a sliding block on horizontal surface why r component is taken negative.

Answer (score 0):

Probably they just chose such a system of coordinates that the coordinates of B are (0,0), coordinates of A are (0,-l), and $\vec{r}$ is directed from B to the block.

Comment: Aren't the coordinates of A (x,0) and of B (0,l)?

Comment: @ChesterMiller : First, it is the block that has coordinate x, whereas, according to the picture, A is a different point. Second, I suspect the solution implies that B was chosen to be the origin.

Comment: Oops.  I mistook the block for point A.

Comment: Please can you elaborate your answer. I'm not getting your point. I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: @AliRaza : I have been criticized here for excessively detailed answers to homework questions ("avoid trying to answer questions which...require too much guidance for you to answer in full" - https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), so I am not going to add anything, sorry. If my answer is not clear enough for you, maybe you should try to somehow improve your knowledge of vectors and coordinate systems.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/557110/217867 please answer it.